# CUDACCompilers[] returns an empty list

Tags: cudalink, gpu

I have just installed Mathematica 11.3.0.0 on Windows 10 (Professional), with an NVIDIA GT 630M GPU on my Dell Inspiron.

I have Visual Studio 2010 Express C++ Compiler installed on my system. I am having trouble having CUDALink to get to recognize it.

Here is what CUDALink setup functions return.

```
CUDAQ[]
```

> `True`

```
CUDADriverVersion[]
```

> `391.35`

```
CUDAResourcesInformation[]
```

> ```
> {{"Name" -> "CUDAResources", "Version" -> "10.5.0", 
>    "BuildNumber" -> "", "Qualifier" -> "Win64", 
>    "WolframVersion" -> "10.5+", "SystemID" -> {"Windows-x86-64"}, 
>    "Description" -> "{ToolkitVersion -> 7.0, MinimumDriver -> 300.0}", 
>    "Category" -> "", "Creator" -> "", "Publisher" -> "", 
>    "Support" -> "", "Internal" -> False, 
>    "Location" -> 
>    "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Paclets\\\
>     Repository\\CUDAResources-Win64-10.5.0", "Context" -> {}, 
>    "Enabled" -> True, "Loading" -> Manual, 
>    "Hash" -> "354b1577ad107387a9b0959358456d58"}}
> ```

If I try the CUDACCompiers[] command the following is the result

```
CUDACCompilers[]
```

> `{}`

Although I have Visual Studio 2010 Express installed on the system. How do I correct it?

Comment: Does `CCompilers[]` work? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html

Comment: No. `CCompilers[]` returns an empty list.

Comment: Can I use a later version of Visual C++ (2012) with CUDALink?